# Tabbed iOS WebKit Browser with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, browser, webkit

In short I am trying to build some typical browser functionalities in a Swift iOS app with WKWebViews (WebKit). I already have a functioning browser based on a WKWebView, which already has a menu bar with a URL input, navigation buttons, a share button, page title etc.

What I am struggling with is creating tabs for the browser. At first this seemed trivial as surely WKWebViews would support this in some way. Well, as far as I can tell they do not (looked at and tried multiple tutorials incl. hackingwithswift, Ray Wenderlich etc. + I checked Apple's documentation + stackoverflow)

This is what I have come up with so far:

1) Creating a new tab/opening a new URL should create a new UIView + WKWebView programmatically (I'll have to make a subclass out of my current browser view)
=> this should create a separate thread for each WKWebView/tab according to Apple's documentation

2) I need something like a Collection View (or Stack Views etc.) to store screenshot images of the already open tabs as a preview page of all tabs. The cells should be linked via a delegate to the corresponding WkWebView and they should have a close button to close (= delete) the tabs.

Am I overthinking this? If I go down this path I have to find a way to wire up (and subsequently delete) multiple delegates and views to the Collection View dynamically and I have to store & delete screenshots every time the user interacts with the tabs. It seems VERY messy. But given that Chrome on iOS is based on WebKit as of late, it's obviously doable.

How would you tackle this problem?

PS I didn't include a mockup because you all know how the tabs in Chrome, Safari etc. on iOS look like.

**EDIT:**
I am just looking for a clean and sensible way to add/remove and show the multiple WKWebViews, which are created by opening new tabs - just like in Chrome for iOS or Safari etc.

Comment: When a new window or tab is created, WKWebview automatically calls: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/initWithFrame:configuration:

Comment: @Brandon yes, that's what I meant with the new threads :) Each WKWebView has a separate thread (as in process) My problem is managing the multiple views when creating new WKWebViews => tying them in both to the UI (tabs) and the code (delegates etc.) i.e. What's the most clean way of creating the Views and binding them to a preview page, which showcases the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this today :) I will have a main UIView and then multiple WKWebViews, which can be "zoomed in" in order to enter full screen mode. No need for screenshots etc.